# MSSQL- Combine two SELECTS, that include JOIN and COUNT

Tags: sql-server, select, join, count

I'm new to Stackoverflow so. Hopefully my question isn't stupid!

I have got two SELECTS which i have to combine. I have tried UNION and another JOIN, but it didnt worked out.

```
SELECT 
Person.Name, Saldo1.Duration AS Holiday, Saldo2.Duraten AS Hours
FROM Person_Saldo AS Saldo1 
JOIN Person_Saldo AS Saldo2 ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Saldo2.Person_ID
JOIN Person ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Person.ID
WHERE Person.Group_ID= '1' AND Person.Active = 'true' AND Saldo1.Year = '2017' AND Saldo1.Timekonto = '4' AND Saldo2.Timekonto='52'
```

and the second SELECT:

```
SELECT
Person_ID, Count([Date]) AS Amount 
FROM Booking Where Timekonto = 54 AND Booking_OK = 1 Group by Person_ID
```

The first SELECT shows something like this:

`Name Holiday Hours
  A    20      50 
  B    12      -30`

The second something like this:

`ID Amount 
  A    4 
  B    3`

What I try:
 `Name Holiday Hours Amount
  A    20      50    4 
  B    12      -30   3`

Thanks, hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to join your aggregation query to your main query like so:

```
SELECT 
    Person.Name
  , Saldo1.Duration AS Holiday
  , Saldo2.Duraten AS Hours
  , b.Amount
FROM Person_Saldo AS Saldo1 
JOIN Person_Saldo AS Saldo2 ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Saldo2.Person_ID
JOIN Person ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Person.ID
left join (
  SELECT Person_ID, Count([Date]) AS Amount 
  FROM Booking 
  Where Timekonto = 54 
    AND Booking_OK = 1 
  Group by Person_ID
  ) b on b.Person_ID = Saldo1
WHERE Person.Group_ID= '1' 
  AND Person.Active = 'true' 
  AND Saldo1.Year = '2017' 
  AND Saldo1.Timekonto = '4' 
  AND Saldo2.Timekonto='52'
```

You may want to use a `left join` instead of an `inner join` if the `count ()` might be `null` for a person that you still want to return in your results.

You could also use [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) or [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the same results.

```
SELECT 
    Person.Name
  , Saldo1.Duration AS Holiday
  , Saldo2.Duraten AS Hours
  , b.Amount
FROM Person_Saldo AS Saldo1 
JOIN Person_Saldo AS Saldo2 ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Saldo2.Person_ID
JOIN Person ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Person.ID
outer apply (
  SELECT Count([Date]) AS Amount 
  FROM Booking as i
  Where i.Person_Id = Saldo1.PersonId
    AND i.Timekonto = 54 
    AND i.Booking_OK = 1 
  ) as b 
WHERE Person.Group_ID= '1' 
  AND Person.Active = 'true' 
  AND Saldo1.Year = '2017' 
  AND Saldo1.Timekonto = '4' 
  AND Saldo2.Timekonto='52'
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "With" in order to make it clearer. You can use left outer join between the two tables.

```
   WITH Table2 as (
   SELECT
   Person_ID, Count([Date]) AS Amount 
   FROM Booking Where Timekonto = 54 AND Booking_OK = 1 Group by Person_ID)


Select Name, Holiday, Hours, Amount
from (SELECT 
    Person.Name, Saldo1.Duration AS Holiday, Saldo2.Duraten AS Hours
    FROM Person_Saldo AS Saldo1 
    JOIN Person_Saldo AS Saldo2 ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Saldo2.Person_ID
    JOIN Person ON Saldo1.Person_ID = Person.ID
    WHERE Person.Group_ID= '1' AND Person.Active = 'true' 
    AND Saldo1.Year = '2017' AND Saldo1.Timekonto = '4'
    AND Saldo2.Timekonto='52') Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table2 on Table2.Person_ID=Table1.Name
```